# How to type assert ad-hoc struct to concrete struct

Tags: go, struct, reflection

I have a question about type assertions between a struct generated with reflect and a normal struct.

I know that this is a very limited use cases, but I would still like to know why it won't work.

https://play.golang.org/p/Ko7e8ysgjCk

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "reflect"
)

type TupleT struct {
    X *big.Int
    Y *big.Int
}

func main() {
    var fields []reflect.StructField
    fields = append(fields, reflect.StructField{
        Name: "X",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(new(big.Int)),
        //Tag:  reflect.StructTag("json:\"" + "x" + "\""),
    })
    fields = append(fields, reflect.StructField{
        Name: "Y",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(new(big.Int)),
        //Tag:  reflect.StructTag("json:\"" + "y" + "\""),
    })
    a := reflect.New(reflect.StructOf(fields)).Elem().Interface()
    if _ = a.(TupleT); true {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    }

    b := new (struct {X *big.Int "json:\"x\""; Y *big.Int "json:\"y\""})
    interf2 := interface{}(b)
    if _ = interf2.(*TupleT); true {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's not how [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) works:

> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that `x` is not `nil` and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`.

A type assertion asserts that the type in the interface value is "exactly" `T`. In your case that doesn't hold. You have an unnamed struct value in the interface, and it cannot be identical to the named type `main.TupleT`. It may be that the types have the same underlying types or that they are convertible, but they are not identical, so the type assertion fails.

You may do what you want if you [*convert*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the value using [`Value.Convert()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Convert):

```
a := reflect.New(reflect.StructOf(fields)).Elem().
    Convert(reflect.TypeOf(TupleT{})).Interface()
if _, ok := a.(TupleT); ok {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Similarly, when using type assertion without using reflection, since the interface value holds a value of an unnamed struct type, you have to type assert that:

```
b := new(struct {
    X *big.Int `json:"x"`
    Y *big.Int `json:"x"`
})
interf2 := interface{}(b)
if _, ok := interf2.(*struct {
    X *big.Int `json:"x"`
    Y *big.Int `json:"x"`
}); ok {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ivoKfx_Svka).

Note that in the 2nd case you also have to specify the struct tags even though in the first example it wasn't needed. The reason for this is because structs with identical fields (not considering tags) are convertible to each other, but they are not identical.